# Java concurrency: how to retrieve data from several thousands TCP sockets at once and synchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to concurrency network programming.

My global task: develop java application which will retrieve temperature from 3000 tcp network devices every 10 seconds synchronously.

Retrieving temperature process/steps:

- Connect to specific IP address through TCP socket (3 seconds timeout)
- Write login/password to socket
- Read temperature from socket
- Close connection

Retrieve temperature from one device takes about 300-400ms.
Summary time of retrieving is 400ms * 3000 = 120 seconds

Need I start 3000 threads for each task for simultaneous retrieving or use queue and thread pool?

Does other ideas exists?

Please put me to right direction.

Comment: If you are "new" to both concepts, this isn't something you should be working on. You need to start with the basics of each and then bring them together later

Comment: What are you doing with temperature of each sensor/device ?

Comment: Put it to shared array and after retrieving done (all devices) will insert from array to Postgresql DB

Comment: If it is at all possible, try not to close the connections or eventually you will not meet your timing constraints.  Do not hit all 3000 devices at once, you have one connection and your connection will terribly degrade.  Find the best balance and do a Round-Robin scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java API for it, Java provides [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) which will let you:

- Create a pool of threads (*and provide you control on how many threads you want in the JVM for this purpose, and JVM manages that pool of threads*).
- Exposes method to specify schedule of the task.

I have provided a sample implementation for you, I have added code comment so that it would be easy for you to understand, you can also refer online documentation or example. Please feel free to let me know in case of any question.

As an aside, if you want the to get results back from the execution of thread then instead of using `Runnable` you can use `Callable` interface which lets you return something, and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has overloaded methods which let you pass a `Callable` object.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorExample {

    private final static int MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2;
    private final static int EXECUTION_SCHEDULE_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS = 5;
    private final static int INITAL_DELAY_IN_SECONDS = 0;

    // set maximum number of threads as per your requirement/performance tuning, for testing set it to "2" and to have better feel.
    private final static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor SCHEDULED_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scheduleTask(new MyRunnableTask("google1.com", 80)); // if you want more fields to set then either use constructor or have setter methods.
        scheduleTask(new MyRunnableTask("google2.com", 80)); // if you want more fields to set then either use constructor or have setter methods.
        scheduleTask(new MyRunnableTask("google3.com", 80)); // if you want more fields to set then either use constructor or have setter methods.
        scheduleTask(new MyRunnableTask("google4.com", 80)); // if you want more fields to set then either use constructor or have setter methods.
    }

    private static void scheduleTask(Runnable runnable) {
        SCHEDULED_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, INITAL_DELAY_IN_SECONDS, EXECUTION_SCHEDULE_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Runnable:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyRunnableTask implements Runnable {

    private String hostName;
    private int port;

    MyRunnableTask(String _hostName, int _port){
        this.hostName = _hostName;
        this.port = _port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.hostName + ":: I am getting executed: " + this.hashCode() + " | " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " | " + new Date());

        // implement your socket programming code here

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to start 3000 threads.  Just start 12 threads - maybe a few more to provide some margin - and divvy up the devices between them.  You'll need to make sure the machine you are running on has the necessary resources, of course.

You might be able to do it in a single thread if you leave the sockets open, depending on just how much of the 400ms is attributable to the actual reading of data and whether the protocol permits multiple reads per login.  This would allow you to do the work while learning only network programming, which would be a lot easier than learning both network programming and multithreaded programming on a single project.

Answer (score 1):

If your task is to connect each device every 10 seconds but actual start time is not important (say some devices are connected at 0:0:0 sec, then 0:0:10, 0:0:20, other devices at 0:0:1, 0:0:11 etc) then you can use 12 threads, as Warren Dew suggested. If all devices must be called over strictly at the same time, then you either have to waste 3 Gigabytes for 3000 threads, or use NIO (e.g Netty library or AsynchronousSocketChannel). Using NIO less reliable - both error prone from programming point of view, and implementation of standard libraries can have bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way:

- Uses [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule your global task
- Uses [Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor--) to init scheduler
- Uses an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to launch all subtask
- Uses [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(???)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) to init subtask thread pool
- Writes a [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) implementation for your subtask
- Uses [ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection< ?>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) to submit all tasks and retrieve their results. You can optionnally use `timeout` version if needed.

Just be aware that a subtask may have thrown an exception when you [get result](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--).

Note: this is a simple solution (easy to implement, which works most of the time, but more limited, might be less performant in your case).

You can achieve better solution using async APIs. Take a look at [AsynchronousSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html) for Promise/Future-based API or [Reactor Netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty) for a more reactive approach.